# How to access Call Log in Android Watch?

Tags: android, wear-os, calllog

I use this code in android app to get the missed call.

```
cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
    Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),
    projection,
    selection,
    selectionArgs,
    sortOrder
);

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String callType = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE));

    String isCallNew = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NEW));

    if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE
            && Integer.parseInt(isCallNew) > 0) {
        missedCallCount++;
}
```

But it doesn't work when i use this code in android watch app. Anyone know  how to access the CALL_LOG in android watch?

I think one of the way to solve this problem is build an app in phone & watch, then phone's app access CALL_LOG and send it to watch's app by using bluetooth. But i want to just build app in watch slide to solve this problem.

Comment: sorry, i missed a close bracket after "missedCallCount++;"

Comment: I need same, is posible, I see a app in play store, delete call logs in Android wear

Answer (score 1):

That information is not available on the watch directly, you'd need to get it from the phone.